# Excel Formula with sumproduct & styear

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out what this formula does, I've read what sumproduct does but what does styear, stmonth, etc do?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(styear=Data!AA$14),--(stmonth=Data!AA$12),--(starea='MTD Sales - Sales Teams'!C9),sthl)+SUMPRODUCT(--(stdyear2=Data!AA$14),--(stdmonth2=Data!AA$12),--(stdarea=C9),stdhl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

styear, stmonth etc. are not **functions**, they are presumably **named ranges** referering to (normally, columns of) data

In Excel 2007 or later go to "Formulas" tab and then click on "Name Manager" - that will list any named ranges and the data to which they refer.

The formula adds together 2 SUMPRODUCT functions, each one sums a range of data based on 3 ranges meeting the specified criteria, if you do have Excel 2007 it would probably be more efficient to do that with SUMIFS